# Pandas: convert unicode elem in column to list

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I have dataframe

```
category    dictionary
Classified  [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'\u043f\u043e', u'\u0443', u'avito', u'\u043e\u0431', u'\u043d\u0438', u'\u043e\u0431\u044a\u044f\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f', u'%8f-', u'\u0434\u043e', u'\u0435\u0449\u0435', u'\u043f\u0440\u0438', u'000', u'\u0436\u0435', u'\u043a\u0430\u043a', u'\u0441\u043e', u'\u0438\u043b\u0438', u'\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440', u'\u0442\u0430\u043a', u'\u043e\u0431\u044a\u044f\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435', u'\u043e\u0431\u044a\u044f\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0439', u'\u0443\u0441\u043b\u0443\u0433', u'\u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442', u'[\u043a\u0430\u043a', u'\u043b\u0438', u'\u043e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043a\u0442', u'avito.', u'###', u'[\u043e', u'\u0444\u043e\u0442\u043e', u'\u0442\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e', u'-avito-', u'\u0434\u043e\u043b\u0436\u043d\u043e', u'\u043d\u0438\u043c']
Search  [u'\u0441', u'\u0443', u'\u043a', u'\u043f\u043e', u'\u043e', u'\u043e\u0431', u'\u0432\u0430\u043c', u'\u0432\u0430\u0448', u'\u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044b', u'\u044f\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441', u'\u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435', u'\u0440\u0430\u0437', u'\u0432\u043e\u0437\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e,', u'\u0441\u0438\u043c\u0432\u043e\u043b\u044b', u'\u044d\u0442\u043e\u043c', u'\u0438\u043b\u0438', u'\u0442\u0430\u043a', u'\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0438', u'\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0443\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0435', u'\u0432\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0433\u043e', u'\u0432\u0430\u0448\u0435\u043c', u'\u0432\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0439', u'\u0432\u043e\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435\u0441\u044c', u'\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u044c\u044e\u0442\u0435\u0440', u'\u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u0442', u'\u043d\u0430\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0440,', u'\u043d\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0439', u'\u043d\u0435\u043e\u0431\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043c\u043e', u'\u043f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430,', u'\u043f\u043e\u0438\u0441\u043a\u0443.', u'\u0440\u0435\u043a\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0434\u0443\u0435\u043c', u'\u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435', u'\u0447\u0442\u043e\u0431\u044b', u'an', u'.ru']
Агрегатор   [u'\u0441', u'\u0443', u'\u043a', u'\u043f\u043e', u'\u043e', u'\u043e\u0431', u'\u0432\u0430\u043c', u'\u0432\u0430\u0448', u'\u0437\u0430\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u044b', u'\u0430\u0432\u0442\u043e\u043c\u0430\u0442\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0435', u'\u044f\u043d\u0434\u0435\u043a\u0441', u'\u0440\u0430\u0437', u'\u0432\u043e\u0437\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e,', u'\u0441\u0438\u043c\u0432\u043e\u043b\u044b', u'\u044d\u0442\u043e\u043c', u'\u0442\u0430\u043a', u'![](//yastatic.net/lego/_/la6qi18z8lwgnzdsar1qy1gwcwo.gif)', u'\u0438\u043b\u0438', u'\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0443\u0437\u0435\u0440\u0435', u'\u0432\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0433\u043e', u'\u0432\u0430\u0448\u0435\u043c', u'\u0432\u0438\u0440\u0443\u0441\u043d\u043e\u0439', u'\u0432\u043e\u0441\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u0443\u0439\u0442\u0435\u0441\u044c', u'\u0435\u0441\u043b\u0438', u'\u043a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u044c\u044e\u0442\u0435\u0440', u'\u043c\u043e\u0436\u0435\u0442', u'\u043d\u0430\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043c\u0435\u0440,', u'\u043d\u0430\u0448\u0435\u0439', u'\u043d\u0435\u043e\u0431\u0445\u043e\u0434\u0438\u043c\u043e', u'\u043f\u043e\u0436\u0430\u043b\u0443\u0439\u0441\u0442\u0430,', u'\u043f\u043e\u0438\u0441\u043a\u0443.', u'\u0440\u0435\u043a\u043e\u043c\u0435\u043d\u0434\u0443\u0435\u043c', u'\u0441\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0430\u0435', u'\u0447\u0442\u043e\u0431\u044b', u'\u043d\u0438']
Аксессуары  [u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'g3', u'lg', u'mypads.ru', u'\u043e', u'[\u0447\u0435\u0445\u043b\u044b', u'\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d', u'dual', u'lte', u'\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d\u043e\u0432', u'mac-set', u'\u043f\u043e', u'\u0443', u'\u043f\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0448\u0435\u0442\u043e\u0432', u'-dual-', u'one', u'\u0441\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0432\u043e\u0437', u'/g3', u'd855/d856/d858', u'|', u'mah', u'[\u0434\u043b\u044f', u'\u0440.', u'sony', u'\u043c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0435', u'\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435\u0444\u043e\u043d\u0430', u'"\u0441\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0432\u043e\u0437', u'"\u043f\u0443\u043d\u043a\u0442', u'dopolnitelnoj-batarei-dlya-telefo-lg', u'\u0441\u0430\u043c\u043e\u0432\u044b\u0432\u043e\u0437\u0430', u'asus', u'circle', u'quick', u'\u0431\u0435\u0441\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0434\u043d\u0430\u044f']
Информационный ресурс   [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'apple', u'\u0443', u'\u043f\u043e', u'apple.com', u'|', u'app', u'store', u'iphone', u'](', u'mail.ru', u'\u043c', u'ipad', u'\u0432\u043e', u'\u0441\u043e', u'\u0433', u'image', u'id', u'\u0434\u043e', u'one', u'\u0442\u0435', u'\u043e\u0431', u'itunes', u'phone', u'le', u'ip', u'apple.', u'\u043f\u0440\u0438', u'\u0436\u0435', u'se', u'os', u'###', u'![](http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4662/as-']
Магазины производителей [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'](/', u'\u0443', u'lenovo', u'\u043f\u043e', u'\u0441\u043e', u'\u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437', u'\u043f\u0440\u0438', u'lenovo](/', u'[\u0430\u043a\u0441\u0435\u0441\u0441\u0443\u0430\u0440\u044b', u'\u0432\u0441\u0435', u'\u0438\u043b\u0438', u'[](javascript:void\\(0\\)', u'\u043f\u043a', u'![](/local/templates/lenovo/images/close-buy-dialog.png)', u'\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0430\u0432\u043a\u0430', u'###', u'\u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0435\u0442-\u043c\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043d', u'[yoga', u'\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0440', u'\u0440\u0443\u0431.', u'\u0440\u0435\u0433\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f', u'\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0434\u0443\u043a\u0442\u044b', u'\u0444\u043e\u0440\u0443\u043c\u0430', u'\u043f\u043e\u043a\u0443\u043f\u043a\u0438', u'\u043f\u043e\u0434\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u043a\u0430', u'\u043e\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0438\u0442\u044c', u'\u0433\u0430\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0442\u0438\u044f', u'lenovo.', u'\u0440\u0430\u043c\u043a\u0430\u0445', u'\u043f\u043e\u0434\u0434\u0435\u0440\u0436\u043a\u0438', u'\u0432\u043e\u0439\u0442\u0438', u'\u043c\u0435\u043d\u044f']
Монобрендовые страницы с информацией    [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'apple', u'\u0443', u'iphone', u'appleinsider.ru', u'mac', u'os', u'\u043f\u043e', u'ios', u'\u0436\u0435', u'macos', u'\u043f\u0440\u0438', u'\u0436', u'[\u043e', u'\u043d\u0438', u'\u043b\u0438', u'macdigger', u'macosworld.ru', u'\u0434\u043e', u'](http://macosworld.ru', u'\u0442\u0430', u'macdigger.', u'macdigger.ru', u'](http://macosworld.ru/', u'](http://www.macdigger.ru', u'login.php?redirect_to=http%3a%2f%2fappleinsider.ru%2fios%2fbystro-', u'razryazhaetsya-iphone-vy-mozhete-emu-pomoch.html)', u'\u043d\u043e\u044f\u0431\u0440\u044c', u'\u2212', u'2015\u0433](http://appleinsider.ru/ios/bystro-razryazhaetsya-iphone-vy-', u'[\u043e\u0442\u0432\u0435\u0442\u0438\u0442\u044c](http://appleinsider.ru/wp-', u'\u043f\u0440\u0438\u043b\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f', u'\u0432\u043e']
Онлайн-магазин  [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'\u0443', u'\u043f\u043e', u'\u0433', u'se', u'\u0434\u043e', u'\u0447', u'](', u'\u0441\u043e', u'\u043d\u0438', u'\u043e\u0431', u'\u0432\u043e', u'\u0442\u0435', u'\u0441\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0444\u043e\u043d', u'smart', u'ip', u'\u043f\u0440\u0438', u'\u043b\u0438', u'\u043e\u0441', u'pro', u'apple', u'phone', u'|', u'aliexpress', u'ebay', u'\u0430\u043a\u0441\u0435\u0441\u0441\u0443\u0430\u0440\u044b', u'dns', u'\u043b', u'\u0436\u0435', u'\u0433\u0431', u'3d', u'\u043a\u0430\u0440\u0442', u'](//static.mvideo.ru/assets/img/stub.gif)']
Официальные и монобрендовые магазины    [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'microsoft', u'\u0443', u'lumia', u'pro', u'sim', u'microsoftstore.ru', u'\u0440.', u'\u043d\u0438', u'\u043f\u043e', u'dual', u'\u0432\u043e', u'\u043e\u0441', u'office', u'3g', u'\u043b\u0438', u'de', u'nokia', u'hp', u'\u0438\u043b\u0438', u'xbox', u'![microsoft', u'windows', u'06', u'\u043f\u0440\u0438', u'lenovo', u'one', u'\u0447\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439', u'361254', u'\u043d\u0443', u'[microsoft', u'spectre', u'###']
Ремонт  [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'mcrf', u'\u0443', u'|', u'mcrf.ru', u'\u043f\u043e', u'ati', u'sony', u'os', u'--', u'se', u'\u0441\u043e', u'\u0432\u043e', u'alva', u'android', u'htc', u'xperia', u'mi', u'](//www.mcrf.ru/forum/styles/mcrf/images/reputation/reputation_highpos.gif)', u'nics', u'\u043b\u0438', u'\u0436\u0435', u'box', u'![alva', u'###', u'\u0442\u0435\u043b', u'\u0434\u043e', u'\u043f\u0440\u0438', u'ns', u'![nics', u'param', u'wp', u'\u0440\u0443\u0431.']
Сайты производителей    [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'microsoft', u'\u0443', u'store', u'|', u'\u043f\u043e', u'windows', u'you', u'one', u'search', u'samsung', u'](javascript:void\\(0\\))', u'lg', u'](', u'](https://www.microsoft.com', u'\u0432\u043e', u'xbox', u'office', u'###', u'support', u'htc', u'account', u'\u0434\u043e', u'javascript', u'&amp;', u'apps', u'+7', u're', u'games', u'mobile', u'phone', u'the', u'lg.com']
Телеком [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'tele2', u'tele2.', u'\u043f\u043e', u'\u0434\u043e', u'\u0440\u0435\u0433\u0438\u043e\u043d', u'\u0443', u'\u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\u0430', u'\u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430', u'\u0440\u0443\u0431.', u'|', u'###', u'\u0442\u0430\u0440\u0438\u0444', u'\u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0435\u0442-\u043c\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0437\u0438\u043d', u'![\u0441\u0430\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043e\u0432', u'\u0442\u0432', u'\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0439\u0442\u0438', u'\u043d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0432', u'\u0431\u0438\u043b\u0430\u0439\u043d', u'\u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d\u0435\u0442', u'[\u0441\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0444\u043e\u043d\u044b', u'\u0433\u0431', u'[\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0435\u043d\u043e\u0441', u'\u0437\u0432\u043e\u043d\u043e\u043a', u'\u043e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c', u'\u0440\u0435\u0433\u0438\u043e\u043d\u0430', u'\u0441\u0430\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f', u'\u0442\u0432\u043e\u0439', u'####', u'\u0441\u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0444\u043e\u043d', u'[\u0438\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f](/info)', u'\u043f\u043b\u044e\u0441', u'\u043e\u0431']
Форумы и отзывы [u'\u043e', u'\u0441', u'\u043a', u'\u0443', u'\u043f\u043e', u'\u0434\u043e', u'\u043e\u0442\u0437\u044b\u0432', u'\u0432\u043e', u'\u043d\u0438', u'\u0442\u0435', u'\u043e\u0431', u'\u0431', u'\u0436\u0435', u'"\u0438\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f', u'\u043f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u0435."', u'de', u'\u0435', u'\u043c', u'\u0444\u043e\u0442\u043e', u'\u043f\u043e\u043b', u'\u0436', u'\u043a\u043e', u'\u0438\u043c', u'\u0432\u0441\u0435', u'\u0441\u043e', u'|', u'\u043f\u0440\u0438', u'\u0432\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0441', u'\u0440', u'\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c', u'_3', u'\u0431\u044b', u'\u044d\u0442\u043e', u'\u043e\u0442\u0437\u044b\u0432\u044b', u'\u0442\u0430\u043a']
```

I need to convert column `dictionary` to lists. These are unicode.
I try

```
lsts = df.dictionary.values.tolist()
for lst in lsts:
    [unicode(i) for i in lst.strip('[]').split(',')]
```

But it doesn't help.

Comment: What fails? Is there an error message? Are you not getting what you expected?

Comment: Can you create an example that is directly copypaste-able? One or two lists in your dictionary are enough.

Comment: @IanS I get unicode again and I can't read elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rlst = []
for lst in lsts:
    ls0 = lst.strip('[] ').split(',')
    rlst.append([unicode(l.lstrip(' u\'').rstrip('\'')) for l in ls0])
```

`rlst` is your result as a list of lists of unicode strings.